# Magento 2 Category Descriptions On Wrong Store View

Tags: magento2

I have a Magento 2.4.6 store, it's just a single store, not a multistore

Therefore there's no store view scope on things like products and categories.

If I go into the admin and change the category description, it saves fine in the admin however it doesn't appear on the frontend.

I've gone into the database and into the table catalog_category_entity_text

When I look at that table there are two entries one for store_id 0 and one for store_id 1

If I update the value for store_id 1 then my changes made in the admin show on the frontend.

Any idea why it's behaving like this? It feels like I need to remove one of the values but I'm not sure which?

[image]

Comment: Please check store list in Admin -> All Stores

Comment: @MPRaj there is only 1 store

Comment: You have to check ID of your store where in store table, also print current store details on front-end. The other thing you can change dropdown to store while saving category(if you find any store please share screenshot for the same). Have you try reindexing?

Comment: @Ankit there is only 1 store, there is no dropdown to change scope.

Comment: Do you migrate this from Magento 1 to Magento 2?

Comment: @Ankit No, it was a fresh install I believe

Comment: Ohk it is difficult to find a solution from here, I got the same problem when I migrate project from M1 to M2.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove once than create again.**